# How to disabled button when form fields is empty or invalid in Ionic 2

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, ionic2

I am new in Ionic 2 and I creating a new form then I want to validation on

form fields I apply validation in **home.ts**

```
export class HomePage {

    user: HomeUser[];

    constructor(public fb: FormBuilder,private homeService: HomeService) {}


    public loginForm = this.fb.group({

        email: ["", Validators.required],
        password: ["", Validators.required]

    });

    doLogin(event) {    

        var user1 =this.loginForm.value;
        //var password = this.loginForm.controls.password.value;
        this.homeService.doLogin(user1).subscribe(user =>this.user = user);

        //console.log(user);

    }
}
```

and my **home.html** file is:-

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="doLogin($event)">
  <div class="row responsive-md">
    <div class="col col-50 col-offset-25">
      <div class="list">
        <label class="item item-input">
          <i class="fa fa-user fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="xyz@gmail.com">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
         <i class="fa fa-lock fa-6" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         &nbsp; &nbsp;
         <input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="***********">
       </label>

       <button class="button button-block button-positive sign_in" type="submit" >
        SIGN  IN
      </button>

      <div class="signup"><span class="donaccount">Don't have an account ?</span> 
       <a href="javascript:;" class="achorsignup"> SIGN UP</a>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I want to disable button when input type is invalid or empty how can I do in ionic 2 App.

Answer (score 3):

put a "disabled" attribute with the following condition.

```
<button type="button" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to provide required attribute for your input fields inside your form, so until the fields are filled in the form signInForm will be invalid. Similarly you could provide other validation attributes on the inputs as well.

Example:-

```
<form name="signInForm">
    <input type="email" ng-model="email" name="email" required />

    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="register()" 
                ng-disabled="signInForm.$invalid">Register</button>

</form>
```

Comment: it is not usful in ionic 2

Comment: You can use this code in tag button [disabled]="!loginForm.valid"